# VBA - Runtime error '1004' with SUMIF function while SUM works fine

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I am writing a fairly simple VBA code in which I want to iterate over the range E2:E6, and add two formula's. The first formula contains entails a SUM function of the column of nearby Table1 and works just fine. The second formula contains a SUMIF function based on the same Table1. However, when running the code, the following error is thrown when reaching the line containing the SUMIF function:

```
Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error
```

I don't know what causes this error, because when printing the output of that line through a `MsgBox` then pasting it in the corresponding cell, the formula works just fine. E.g., in the first iteration, the formula produced by the last line of code is `=$E$2*SUMIF(Table1[Column1];$D$2;Table1[Column2])`, which delivers the correct result when pasted in corresponding cell G2. Any ideas on what causes this error?

My worksheet:

[image: A screenshot of my worksheet]

The VBA code:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim workSheet As workSheet
    Set workSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = workSheet.Range("E2:E6")
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=" + Rng.Address + "*SUM(Table1[Column2])"
        Rng.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=" + Rng.Address + "*SUMIF(Table1[Column1];" + Rng.Offset(0, -1).Address + ";Table1[Column2])"  'This line causes the error
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula` - change to `Rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaLocal`

Comment: (Or, change the semi-colons in your formula to commas)

Comment: Also note that you don't need a loop. `workSheet.Range("E2:E6").Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=E2*SUMIF(Table1[Column1], D2, Table1[Column2])"` will do.